# Save one part of an association if parameters are missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The association creates a customer_order and payment. I want to be able to save customer_order alone IF a payment_amt is missing.

If I try and save now without a payment_amt the save fails because its trying to save to both models.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eTjUanQFPW1haHqfIALNLvDfHEe4TMxYo1OL8XpbZXX9MOiGcqpLrd9rVKksnxblzu2IKzwFx7pwTvDFWAKcNA==", "customer_order"=>{"dba_id"=>"20", "order_amt"=>"100", "payments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"payment_amt"=>"", "transaction_id"=>"1234", "transaction_type"=>"CHK"}}, "magazine_id"=>"339", "years"=>"2", "lead_id"=>"594", "mailer_id"=>"", "source"=>"custom entry", "new_or_renewal"=>"N"}, "commit"=>"Create Customer order", "controller"=>"customer_orders", "action"=>"create"}
```

As you can see below, the payment is missing. In that case I just want to save the customer order, which will create a bill me later scenario.

```
@customer_order.payments
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Payment id: nil,  payment_amt: nil, transaction_type: "CHK", transaction_id: "1234",   deposit_id: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, customer_order_id: nil, deposit_created_at: nil>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments` in your CustomerOrder model. Change it to:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments, reject_if: proc { |payment| attributes['payment_amt'].blank? }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the association if the payment information is missing

```
@customer_order.payments.delete_all
```

Then I save the customer_order alone.